# Get lifetime sales of a website using soap API

Tags: orders, api, sales, soap

How to get lifetime sales value and orders of a website via soap API v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a ready to go method for this but you could use the *invoice.list* and the *creditmemo.list* API's to calculate the sales.

Documentation on the Invoice API you can find [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.list.html) and on the Creditmemo API [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderCreditMemo/sales_order_creditmemo.list.html).

You can use a past date like 01-01-1970 up to todays date to filter on all invoices or creditmemos, retrieving all of them and using the `grand_total` records to retrieve the lifetime sales.

A small warning, the API will get quite slow when retrieving that much info. You might want to think about creating your own WSDL in Magento to retrieve the data.
There is some nice documentation on this topic by [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/) and one post on the [Magento Board](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43818/)